# How to edit the layout of Laravel jet steam profile?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to edit the layout of the jet steam profile:

[image: jet steam profile]

to match my needs, how can I set my own `navbar` and change the layout using bootstrap?

I tried to include everything from the home page (my own index) but that didn't change anything

keep in mind that I need user information as it's set in the original layout, I just need to improve the design

any idea?

Comment: Which Jetstream stack are you using?

Comment: @Unflux Livewire + Blade

Answer (score 1):

Using the Livewire stack for Jetstream, you'll want to publish the [view components](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/stacks/livewire.html#components):

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

The view components will then be made available in your `resources/views` directory. From there you can customise them.

As Jetstream uses Tailwindcss out of the box, you'll also want to include bootstrap either pulling it in via a CDN or including it as part of your build pipeline.